# Passing and Accessing a JSON Object and a CSV file in a FormData

Tags: javascript, java, json, reactjs, fetch

I want to pass a `JSON Object` and a `CSV file` in a fetch call from my frontend to my backend.

`headerIngestion` is the JSON and I have the file saved in the `csv` state

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('header', headerIngestion);
formData.append('file', this.state.csv);

fetch('http://localhost:8080/...', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            })
            .then ...
```

I have this so far for my sever that uses SpringBoot as originally i only passed the csv file.

```
@PostMapping(URL)
public String ingestDataFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        byte[] bytes;
        try {
            bytes = file.getBytes();
            String completeData = new String(bytes);
            System.out.println(completeData);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return "something";
}
```

What do I need to do to be able to access the `JSON` and the `file` separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of playing around, this worked

```
public String ingestDataFile(@RequestPart("header") String json,
        @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
```